# How do you insert a single row into Google sheets using Sheets APIv4 Java

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

If I want to insert a row into Google sheets using Java at a specified index, then write to that row, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out after lots of googling, some struggling and [adapting another answer](/a/48286666/1146032).

**Note:** You can generate [your own `credentials.json`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java). This goes in your "resources" folder in most IDEs.

Here's the code that I used, in full – the relevant method that you will need is the `insertRow` method below, which is invoked from `writeTest`  Under normal circumstances I would just post the method in question, but the "quickstart" in the sheets API is definitely lacking so here's the full source:

**Class & Imports**

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SheetsTest {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Metrics project";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";
```

**getCredentials**:

```
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException{
    InputStream in = SheetsTest.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}
```

**writeTest**

```
//Creates a new row at row 2 then writes data to it...
static void writeTest(Report r, String sheetID, String range)throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException{
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    ValueRange requestBody = requestBuilder(r, range);
    Sheets sheetsService = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    insertRow(sheetsService, sheetID);
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Append request =
            sheetsService.spreadsheets().values().append(sheetID, range, requestBody);
    request.setValueInputOption("RAW");
    //request.setInsertDataOption("INSERT_ROWS");
    AppendValuesResponse resp = request.execute();

    System.out.println(resp);
}
```

**insertRow**

```
//Inserts row at index, this is hardcoded to row 2 (0-indexed)
private static void insertRow(Sheets ss, String sheetID)throws IOException{
    InsertDimensionRequest insertRow = new InsertDimensionRequest();
    insertRow.setRange(new DimensionRange().setDimension("ROWS").setStartIndex(1).setEndIndex(2).setSheetId(0));

    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest r = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(Arrays.asList(
            new Request().setInsertDimension(insertRow)
    ));
    ss.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(sheetID, r).execute();
}
```

**requestBuilder**

```
//Populate ValueRange
static ValueRange requestBuilder( Report r, String range){
    ValueRange v = new ValueRange()
        .setValues(Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(r.value1),
            Arrays.asList(r.value2),
            Arrays.asList(r.value3),
            Arrays.asList(r.value4),
            Arrays.asList(r.value5)
        ))
        .setMajorDimension("ROWS")
        .setRange(range)
    ;
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not allowed to comment on Elric's answer, but I would just like to make a correction.

To add a single row with your values, in the method:

**requestBuilder** \

It should be `.setMajorDimension("COLUMNS")` instead of `"ROWS`.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: It worked for me as-is, but I'm happy to upvote this in case it helps anyone.

Comment: I had this running in production for a while as-is and I remember there being some weird shit when I had columns rather than rows and it was somehow inverted, but I left the job that I was at where I was doing this.   Luckily I'll have to do this again in the near future....